# Spring application working in eclipse but same not working when deployed on tomcat 8

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, spring-security

I am using maven, eclipse. Everything is fine when running from eclipse.
But same if I deploy on tomcat it returns http status 404.
log says No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath but I am using web.xml

I am not able to figure out issue here, if anybody can help please.
There is no issue with filter and servlet mapping.

web.xml

contextClass
        org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext

```
<!-- Location of Java @Configuration classes that configure the components 
    that makeup this application -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.asuare.temapp</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.sessionSupport</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Specifies the default mode of this application, to be activated if 
    no other profile (or mode) is specified -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
    <param-value>mysql</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- Secures the application -->
```

securityFilter
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        
            targetBeanName
            springSecurityFilterChain
        
        true

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Handles requests into the application -->
<servlet>

    <servlet-name>temapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.MeteorServlet</servlet-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.servlet</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- No explicit configuration file reference here: everything is configured 
            in the root container for simplicity -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>temapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter
    </filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>    
</filter-mapping>

<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/denied</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/restapi/denied</location>
</error-page>
```

server log:

> 24-Jul-2016 13:20:57.816 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring
>   WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath 24-Jul-2016
>   13:20:58.331 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring
>   root WebApplicationContext 24-Jul-2016 13:21:25.913 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring
>   FrameworkServlet 'sportingEasy' 24-Jul-2016 13:21:42.699 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring
>   WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath 24-Jul-2016
>   13:22:02.971 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring
>   WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath 24-Jul-2016
>   13:22:03.034 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener:
>   contextInitialized() 24-Jul-2016 13:22:03.034 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener:
>   contextInitialized() 24-Jul-2016 13:22:48.611 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring
>   WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath

Comment: Are you using spring-boot?

Comment: no not using spring-boot.

Comment: Yes I tried clean install, build, process-classes..

Comment: can you post your web.xml and your pom.xml ?

Comment: I have added my web.xml

Comment: In order to see Spring initialization messages (mainly the request mapping) during the server startup we need a stack log report.

Comment: your <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> is not firing the Dispatcherservlet because -temapp- is pointing to some other class. Not 100% sur but you should consider this aspect.

Comment: Even with url pattern /*  it's not working

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. My maven had tomcat7 plugin but the JRE environment was 1.6. I changed my tomcat7 to tomcat6 and the error was gone.Could you check once your JRE environment and try.
Also please add the 'maven-war-plugin' version 2.6 in your pom.xml

Comment: you mean to say it was working in eclipse but not in standalone tomcat? and after these steps it started working in standalone tomcat.

Comment: issue was with the tomcat verison